# Web3j doesn't observe new blocks/transactions

Tags: web3j

I'm using Web3j 3.2.0 and Infura to get information about new blocks and transactions in Ethereum.

```
    val web3j = Web3j.build(HttpService("https://mainnet.infura.io/<mytoken>"))
    log.info("Connected to Ethereum client version: ${web3j.web3ClientVersion().send().getWeb3ClientVersion()})

    val startingBlock = DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(BigInteger.valueOf(4866661))

    web3j.catchUpToLatestAndSubscribeToNewTransactionsObservable(startingBlock)
        .filter { !it.value.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) }
        .subscribe {
            println("Block #${it.blockNumber}: ${it.blockHash.substring(2..8)}.. -- Transaction Index: ${it.transactionIndex} -- From ${it.from} To ${it.to} -- Value ${it.value}")
        }
```

My code does the scan and shows all the blocks but doesn't continue scanning for future blocks. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Using web3j 3.5.0 and the Infura WebSocket endpoint, you can subscribe to an Observable to capture new block events:

```
String url = "wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws";

// Connection to the node
WebSocketService web3jService = new WebSocketService(url, true);
web3jService.connect();
web3j = Web3j.build(web3jService);

String clientVersion = web3j.web3ClientVersion().send().getWeb3ClientVersion();
System.out.println(String.format("Connected to Ethereum node %s : %s", url, clientVersion));

// Subsribe to blocks
web3j.blockObservable(false).subscribe(block -> {
    System.out.println("NEW BLOCK -> " + block.getBlock().getNumber().intValue());
});
```

And this is the output

```
Connected to Ethereum node wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws : Geth/v1.8.15-omnibus-255989da/linux-amd64/go1.10.1
NEW BLOCK -> 6742046
NEW BLOCK -> 6742047
NEW BLOCK -> 6742048
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this [problem is related to the INFURA filters](https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/13)